# Result in new window - PHP + HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need my results to be displayed in a new window. Here is my code. What changes should i make in it to obtain results in new window. I tried with onclick(window.open()) but I am not sure what will be my target url. kindly help me in this regard.

```
<style type="te<td>xt/css">
.style29 tr tbody tr td p strong {
font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
</style>

<TABLE class=style29 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=600
            bgColor=#fdf7f2 border=0 align = "center">
              <TR>

       <form name="MicRooN">
<tr> <td align ="center" bgcolor = #f6cece> <h1><big><big><strong><B style = "COLOR:#FF0000">Mi</B>c<B style = "COLOR:#FF0000">R</B>oo<B style = "COLOR:#FF0000">N</B>&nbsp;</strong></big></big></h1>
</td>
<! this is for the about the tool >
<tr >
<td >
<!--
<fieldset><legend><B>About the Tool</B></legend>
MicRooN (an acronym of miRNA), a tool for identification of miRs associated with cancer. Its a ensemble based classifier[LIBSVM,C4.5 & Random Forest], built on experiementally validated set of miRs associated with cancer. The tool aims in identifying novel miR associated in cancer pathway.
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
-->

<br></fieldset>
<! this is for the Input>
<tr>
<td><fieldset><legend><B>Input</B></legend>
<p align = "center">
<form method = "post" action="/">
    <center>Input miR ID :<input name = "miRNA" id ="textfeild" type = "text" placeholder="hsa-mir-532-3p" /></p>
    Input Target :<input name = "target" id ="textfeild" type = "text" placeholder="RCN2" /></p></center>
    <p align="center"> <input id="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit" /> 

    </form>

    <button onclick="window.location.assign('http:\\')" />Clear</button>
    <br><br>
<p style="text-align: center;">Format for miR ID :
hsa-mir-6793&nbsp;<br />
(As per <A href  = "http://www.mirbase.org">miRBASE </A>format)</p>
 </fieldset>  </td>
</tr>
<! this is for the output>



<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST["miRNA"])){
    $dummy = true;
}
else{
    goto foot;
}
?>


<tr>
<td align="center" ><fieldset><legend>Output</legend><br>
<style>
#output tr td{
    border:1px solid black;
}
.bold{
    font-size:18px;
    text-decoration:bold;
}
</style>
<table id="output" style="border:1px solid black;">
    <tr class="bold">
        <td>EnsembleID</td>
        <td>Target</td>
        <td>Gene Length</td>
        <td>miRNA</td>
        <td>miRNA Length</td>
        <td>mfe</td>
        <td>P-value</td>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Prediction</td>
        <td>No of Seeds</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $a = $_REQUEST["miRNA"];
        $b = $_REQUEST["target"];
        // $result = db::table("`table`") -> pluck("*") -> where("miRNA",$a) -> select() -> get();
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "mysql");
        $a = $mysqli -> escape_string($a);
        $b = $mysqli -> escape_string($b);
        $a = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `bio2` where miRNA = '$a' and Target like '%$b' ORDER BY  `bio2`.`pvalue` ASC;");
        // $result = $a -> fetch_assoc();
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $a -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $result[$i] = $row;
            $i++;

        }
        $mysqli->close();
        for($a=0;$a<sizeof($result);$a++){
            print '<tr>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["Ensemble_ID"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["Target"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["Gene_Length"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["miRNA"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["miRNA_Length"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["mfe"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["pvalue"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["position"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["Prediction"]).'</td>
                    <td>'.htmlentities($result[$a]["no_of_seeds"]).'</td>
                </tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
    table{
        text-align: center;
    }
    td{
        min-width: 100px;
    }
</style>
<?php
if(sizeof($result) == 0){
    print "<h3 style='color:red;'>miRNA record not found</h3>";
}
?>
<br><br></fieldset> </td>
</tr>

<?php

foot:
?>

<! this is for the reference>
<tr>
<td>
<fieldset><legend><B>Reference</B></legend>
<ul>
<li> "Search for signatures in miRNAs associated with cancer", Kothandan R, Biswas S, Bioinformation, Vol.9(10) <A href = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=23861569"><B> [PMID:23861569] </B></A> </li>
<li> "Sequence Trademarks in oncogene associated microRNAs", Sharma S, Biswas S, Bioinformation, Vol.6(9) <A href = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=21814397"><B> [PMID:21814397] </B></A> </li>
</ul>
<br></fieldset>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<footer align = "center"> &#169 Vista Lab Copyright 2013-2014, Sumit Biswas & Ram K. All righs reserved. | Disclaimer </footer>
<?php
$x = file_get_contents("./view/counter");
file_put_contents("./view/counter", $x+1);
print "<center>page view = $x<br>";
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
print "you ip is".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."</center>";
file_get_contents("./view/ip");
$str = "Access from ".$ip."\n";
$log = file_get_contents("./view/ip");
$log = $log.$str;
file_put_contents("./view/ip", $log);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the property target:

```
<form action="/result.php" method="post" target="_blank">
```

Comment: Sorry , this method shows me the result but the input feildset also appears with the result.

Comment: So put your code of result in other page and change the action of your form

Answer (score 0):

Create new page (http page) for your require functionality to show under new window. and point the newly created page url in click window code.

Or you can use native javascript to write you content in window.
For example:

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
}
</script>
```

You can notice from `myfunction` function doing couple of task, first it will generate new window object secondly we writing something under newly created window object and then fire it successfully.

By this method we do not need to worry about url to hit.

Comment: Actually, the query result is my output . I don't how to redirect them to new window. If i am using java script how do  I write my results in new window.

Comment: Let me rephrase your requirement. you want to open new url of your site right when you get something appropriate rIght! in this regards you need to redirect to new result page where you will perform all the query result which behave as separate page using window.location or window.href javascript. or by using php header function.
It's make sense?

Comment: Yes.. Correct. I need my results alone in new page. I used target artribute but my input feildset also displays. I need only results in new page. .My question is in window.location () .. What will be my location.

Comment: Well, i don't think so, you submitting your form to `/`path. catch the submitted form using php and by completing your task just redirect to new url 
hint code: ``header('Location: http://www.example.com/');``